# Flutter Web SIdemenu StateManagement

Tags: flutter, web, scrollcontroller

I am building web app. Everything working fine.
I have created different page for each routes.
Like Dashboard,Transaction,Entry,Report.

on each page I use same widget of SideMenu.
When I move from 1 page to another its SideMenu scrollposition is on top,
Because its generate sidemenu as new widget.
I want to store last position of sidemenu.

How can I achieve this?

or

Can I create single instance and use that instance everywhere.
Currently its creating new widget on each page.

Please guid me what to do?